# Добавление JMF в Eclipse

Tags: java

Начинаю изучать JMF. Библиотека добавлена в проект, но при его запуске возникает ошибка:

> The source attachment does not contain
> the source for the file
> JMFSecurityManager.class.

Для всех jar-файлов в библиотеке Source Attachment установлены (те же jar-файлы).

Ошибка возникает на строке

```
  player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mlr);
```

Код взят для первого пробного знакомства с JMF отсюда:

[Захват изображения с веб-камеры при помощи JMF](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread230884.html)

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Main m = new Main();
          m.setVisible(true);
}
public Main() {
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            player.stop();
            player.deallocate();
            player.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setSize(640, 480);
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    String mediaFile = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
    try {
        MediaLocator mlr = new MediaLocator(mediaFile);
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mlr);
        player.setRate(100);
        if (player.getVisualComponent() != null) {
            panel.add("Center", player.getVisualComponent());
        }
        if (player.getControlPanelComponent() != null) {
            panel.add("South", player.getControlPanelComponent());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got exception " + e);
    }
}

Player player; 
}
```